# Indefinite article “a”

Tags: grammaticality

1) Established in 2000 by a brand consultant, James Bond, Nike became ~~

2) Established in 2000 by brand consultant, Jame Bond, Nike became~~

Which one is right? Should I put “a” or not?

Comment: (1) is grammatical but sounds rather weak. Compare 'Having the honour of meeting a prince, Michael, last week ....' (2) tacitly assumes that readers will be au fait with all that  'brand consultant' implies, and is better, but should not have the comma after 'brand consultant'. We would not write _Liverpool manager, Jürgen Klopp is doing a fine job_.

Comment: The second version should not have the comma.